# Jquery not working in Safari

Tags: jquery

Hi could anybody work out why this would not work in Safari? its taken from code by Yi Jiang. Many Thanks

```
<div id="profile-list"></div> 

<script>
   var classes = ['email-checkout', 'absc', 'random', 'brrrr'];

   for (var i = 0; i < 6000; i++) {
    $('<input />').attr({
     type: 'checkbox',
     class: classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)],
     checked: (Math.random() > .5)
    }).appendTo('#profile-list');
   }  
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not work"? What errors do you get in the error console?

Comment: Hi Chris it was just showing a blank page. You will probably be horrified to know that I'm not quite sure how to use the error console. Do you mean in Firebug? An explanation would be appreciated though.

Answer (score 2):

`class` is a reserved word, you need to quote it like this:

```
"class": classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)],
```

I'm not *sure* this is why Safari's failing...but it would certainly fail in IE for this reason.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at the developer console and it gave a parse error that `class` is a reserved word. If you change your options to be quoted, then it works:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    $('<input />').attr({
        "type": 'checkbox',
        "class": classes[Math.floor(Math.random() * classes.length)],
        "checked": (Math.random() > .5)
    }).appendTo('#profile-list');
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for looking in to this, regards James