# jQuery not working in Safari - why not?

Tags: jquery, safari

I have a form with several submit buttons, and I want to get the ID of the clicked button. I use this:

```
var ID = $(this).find("input[type=submit]:focus").attr('id');
```

It is working fine in Chrome, IE and Firefox, but NOT in Safari - why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397804/jquery-not-working-in-safari)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
```

If not, according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) you should be able to utilize getElementById().

Reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById for an example of utilizing getElementById().

Or pass it through @ the onclick event of the buttons like:

```
onClick="whateverYourFunction(this.id)"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I try: $(this).attr(‘id’); I get the id of the form